# Show that $\dfrac{1}{log(n)}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{X_{k}}{k} \to^{a.s} 0 $, when $n \to \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, random-variables

I hace this question in my probability homework, but it is fun because it is only necessary know analysis. Help me please

Let {$X_{n}: n \geq 1$} be independent random variables. Show that if $X_{n} \to^{a.s} 0$ then $\dfrac{1}{log(n)}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{X_{k}}{k} \to^{a.s} 0 $, when $n \to  \infty$

Comment: This is an exercise in Analysis. It does not require any Probability Theory.

Comment: How can I apply the following definition? A sequence of random variables {$X_{n}: n \geq 1 $} converges almost surely to a random variable X, shown by  $X_{n} \to ^{a.s} X$, if P({$ s \in S : \lim_{n \to \infty} X_{n} (s)=X(s)$})=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you use that for $x_n \to 0$ we have $$\frac 1 {\log n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac {x_k} k \to 0$$then it follows that $$\left\{s \in S : \frac{1}{\log n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac {X_n (s)} k \to 0 \right\} \supset \left\{s \in S : X_n(s) \to 0 \right\}.$$Hence we are done.
Just because it's a fun exercise let me write down, why the first statement holds, so let $(x_n)_n$ be a real sequence with $x_n \to 0$. We will use that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 k \le \log n$. Also let $\varepsilon >0$ be arbitrary and $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ be big enough, s. th. $\lvert x_n \rvert < \frac \varepsilon 2 $ for all $n > n_0$ and $n_1$ be big enough, s.th. $$\frac 1 {\log n} < \frac \varepsilon 2 \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n_0} \frac {x_k} k \right)^{-1} $$for all $n > n_1$. Then we have $$\frac 1 {\log n } \sum_{k=1}^n \frac {x_k} k = \frac 1 {\log n } \sum_{k=1}^{n_0} \frac {x_k} k + \frac {\sup_{k> n_0} x_k} {\log n } \sum_{k=n_0 + 1}^n \frac 1 k < \frac \varepsilon 2 + \frac {\log n} {\log n } \cdot \frac \varepsilon 2  = \varepsilon $$ for all $n> n_1$.

Comment: yeah! That's true, is a fun exercise Thank you.